# How to use the right analog stick of a xbox one controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, joystick, xbox-one

How would I get the right joystick on an Xbox one controller? I currently have my `InputManager` set up like this:

[image: My InputManager]

But this doesn't work for some odd reason. For those of you wondering I have confirmed that the issue isn't in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the the "rightStickVertical"  is the 5th Axis while the Horizontal for the Right stick is the  4th Axis.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1350081/xbox-one-controller-mapping-solved.html

Comment: Ok, I get it, but is there any reason, in particular, it isn't just `x-axis` and `y-axis`?

Comment: Seems that  x-axis and y-axis are for the left joystick